# Why does MySQL 8 starts the server with --super-read-only flag on Windows Startup?

Tags: mysql

I've just installed MySQL Server 8.0.20 with a new InnoDB Cluster and configured to Start it at System Startup. Everything works fine, except when I try to create a new Table I get this Error:

`The MySQL server is running with the --super-read-only option so it cannot execute this statement`

How can I turn off this option?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to run `dba.rebootClusterFromCompleteOutage('clusterName')` in order to reboot it.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the DB server participate in a replication cluster which someone/admin requested it to be in a "read only" state.
So make sure you are not changing something there that you shouldn't.

See:
https://www.percona.com/blog/using-the-super_read_only-system-variable/
which says:

> It is well known that replica servers in a master/slave configuration,
> to avoid breaking replication due to duplicate keys, missing rows or
> other similar issues, should not receive write queries.